# Rav Hirsch and zachor

Tags: sources-mekorot, pentateuch-chumash, commentaries, samson-raphael-hirsch

Rav Shimshon Raphael Hirsch says that the word *zachor* (in [Exodus 20:7](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0220.htm#7)), meaning remember, is the statement telling us "to keep the Shabbos in our minds and hearts, and give verbal expression to its holiness."

Rav Hirsch is quoted as such in the Artscroll Siddur's commentary on לכה דודי (on the words, "שמור וזכור בדבור אחד") which can be found in the interlinear Artscroll Shabbos Siddur, page 71.

Does anyone know the original source where Rav Hirsch says this?

Answer (score 6):

To paraphrase R' Hirsch's comments on *Sh'mos* 20:7:

> The Talmud ([*Sh'vu'os* 20b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=26&daf=20b&format=text)) remarks that the words *zachor* (remember) and *shamor* (guard/observe) were said at the same time. This indicates that these two aspects of Shabbos are intertwined. The Jewish Sabbath does not entail mere spiritual recollection. Such an approach would rob Shabbos of its essential character.
>
> For the Jewish people, the obligation to remember the Shabbos (*zachor*) is an obligation to perform acts that focus our hearts on the significance of the day. From this, the reason behind many of the laws of Shabbos becomes clear. First of all, "recall it over wine at its onset" ([*P'sachim* 106a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=4&daf=106&format=text)), which is the *mitzva* to sanctify the day with *kiddush*...

R' Hirsch's comments can be seen more fully in Hebrew [here](http://alhatorah.org/Decalogue_Differences_Between_Shemot_and_Devarim/5):

Comment: Why would you include the Hebrew on this English-language site? I can understand including the Hebrew when it's the author's original, so as to catch any nuances that the translation omits, but here it isn't. (He wrote his commentary in German.) +1, though.

Comment: @msh210 I included it because it is more extensive than my partial English paraphrasing. If you think it's distracting, I'll get rid of the Hebrew and only leave the link to it.

Comment: No, I was just wondering. Seemed odd, especially since an English translation is widely available (but maybe not where you are?).