# Based on Ramban [Shemot 20:10] גֵרְךָ אֲשֶׁר בִּשְׁעָרֶיךָ , Noachides observe Shabbat by not serving B'nei Yisrael (but can work for Noachides)?

Tags: shabbat, noachide-laws, ramban

**Should Noachides be reminded Ramban's commentary on [Shemot 20:10](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.20.10?lang=bi&with=Ramban&lang2=en)?** - Based on Ramban analysis of Shabbat laws : גֵרְךָ אֲשֶׁר בִּשְׁעָרֶיךָ , Noachides must observe Shabbat by not serving/benefiting B'nei Yisrael (but can work/profit to benefit themselves & other Noachides). - Correct?

> "NOR THY STRANGER THAT IS WITHIN THY GATES. In line with the plain meaning of Scripture, “the stranger of the gate” is always the geir toshav, who came to dwell in “the gates of our cities” and has taken upon himself the Seven Laws of the Noachides. It is he who is called “the stranger who eats the unlawfully-slaughtered animal,” of whom Scripture says, thou mayest give it to the stranger that is within thy gates, that he may eat it. Therefore, the commandment [prohibiting work on the Sabbath] was not directed to him so that Scripture would be saying: “Do not do any work on it, the home-born or the stranger.” Instead, it is we who are commanded that he do no work for our benefit, just as [we are commanded about] our minors and the cattle, but this commandment is not incumbent upon him and he may do work for himself on the Sabbath. The verse which states, so that the son of thy handmaid, and the stranger, may rest, speaks of the righteous proselyte who has become Jewish and embraced our Torah, which has commanded him concerning the Sabbath and all the rest of the commandments as well, as He has said, One law and one ordinance shall be both for you, and for the stranger that sojourneth with you; both for the stranger, and for him that is born in the land. However, we have found in the words of our Rabbis that they have interpreted it in the opposite manner. Thus they have said that by way of the plain meaning of Scripture, thy stranger that is within thy gates means the righteous proselyte, and ceasing from work [on the Sabbath] is incumbent upon him as it is upon us. The verse, so that the son of thy handmaid, and the stranger, may rest, includes the uncircumcised geir toshav. The Rabbis’ intent in so explaining the verses is that first, [i.e., right here in the Ten Commandments], “the stranger” warned is the proselyte who has been circumcised, who is obligated in the observance of the Sabbath as we are. The second verse — [further, 23:12] — includes the uncircumcised [geir toshav]. Therefore, he is likened there to the cattle, as the verse says, that thine ox and thine ass may have rest, and the son of thy handmaid, and the stranger, may rest. Thus He commanded us concerning the resting of all of them alike that they should not work for us, but they may do [work] for themselves if they so wish."

Comment: To be clear, this is not a hiddush of the Ramban. This is based on Yebhamoth 48b/Kerithuth 9a and is brought down in the codes (e.g. H. Shabboth 20:14). A Ger Toshabh may not perform labor on Shabboth for a Jew. However the Ger Toshabh may perform labor on Shabboth for himself.

Comment: @Deuteronomy - From fear of potentially performing labor for unrighteous B'nei Yisrael, should Noachides not labor at all on Shabbat to make sure Shemot 20:10 is not violated?

Comment: A gentile may not fully observe Shabboth. See H. Melakhim 10:11 גוי שעסק בתורה, חייב מיתה; לא יעסוק אלא בשבע מצוות שלהן בלבד.  וכן גוי ששבת--אפילו ביום מימות החול--אם עשה אותו לעצמו כמו שבת, חייב מיתה; ואין צריך לומר אם עשה מועד לעצמו.

Comment: @Deuteronomy - The issue is Judaism has taught Noachides don't keep Shabbat, when in fact HaShem commanded them to observe Shabbat by not serving/benefiting B'nei Yisrael. > Why does Judaism not help Noachides understand their role with Yisrael? - Shemot 20:10 gives Noachides a legal defense for their own religious observance of Shabbat (if unrighteous Israelites demand their labor on Shabbat).

Comment: @חִידָה If a Noachide cannot readily determine whether or not the person they are working for is a Jew, I suspect one could assume that any given person is non-Jewish ("רוב העולם עובדי כוכבים הם") unless there's reason to suspect otherwise (such as if the Noachide is in an area where the majority of people are Jews). But that would be a good question for you to [ask](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)!

Comment: [Rabbi Yudan](https://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/15127-yudan) addresses the dual expressions of the Almighty's command to observe the Shabbos found in the Ten Commandments: "Remember" ([Exod. 20:7](https://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0220.htm#7) "זכור") and "Guard" ([Deut. 5:11](https://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0505.htm#11) "שמור"). In *Pesikta Rabbasi* ([23](https://www.sefaria.org/Pesikta_Rabbati.23.1), "אמר ר' יודן זכור נתן לאומות העולם שמור נתן לישראל") he says that non-Jews should primarily observe Shabbos via the "Remember" element. Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/52652